# Low memory Java application server

Tags: java, memory, application-server

We have developed a lightweight Jersey/JSON/JMS Java application which acts as a connector between the customers legacy MS Access system and our application server. This connector is installed on the customers server.

We have used Glassfish 3.1.2 as application server so far, but the memory consumption is enormous (400 - 900 MB only hosting this particular application, even in Web Profile!).

We are looking for a lightweight application server which is easy to use (supporting JDBC/ODBC, Jersey, JMS and Custom JNDI Resources), uses less than 300 MB of memory and has a Web GUI for configuration and deployment.

Which application servers whould fit our needs? Is there a way to reduce the memory consumption of Glassfish to under 400 MB?

Comment: Have you considered profiling your application's memory usage?

Comment: The problem is, Glassfish without any applications installed consumes way over 400 MB of ram on a 64 Bit system, and this is definitely too much for this small application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution.
Since our application doesn't require much memory, a 32 Bit Glassfish instance satisfies our needs. It uses with the Admin GUI and our application running around 250 MB of memory, which is OK. Jetty may use less memory, but has no Admin GUI and furthermore, its easier for us to manage one type of application server than two.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty). Jetty provides an HTTP server, HTTP client, and [javax.servlet](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/package-summary.html) container.

It's commonly used for in-container unit testing of servlet code, because it's a fast-starting, cut-down Java EE server container, but it is nevertheless a real application server.

Comment: OK, thank you. I will give it a try and post my results here. More suggestions are welcome! It does not seem that there is a Web Admin GUI for Jetty?